# How to remove old or past events in google calendar?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to delete past Calendar events which are no longer being used. Deleting the event should not remove future repeating events. How do I implement using google apps script?

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is no known softwares till now to implement, after your problem statement I was successful to create a one, which you could run after authorizing your google calendar.

```
function doGet() { /* Get your default calendar */
    var cal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
    var yest = new Date().getTime() - 86400000; //milliseconds in a day

    var start = new Date(0);
    var end = new Date(yest);

    /* Get all events from start date upto time */
    var events = cal.getEvents(start, end)

    var body = "Calendar - Events Log - Status" + "\n\n-----------------------\n";

    if (events.length > 0) {
        var tz = Session.getScriptTimeZone();

        /* Build-up log */
        for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
            body += Utilities.formatDate(events[i].getStartTime(), tz, "MM:dd HH:mm") + " ～ ";
            body += Utilities.formatDate(events[i].getEndTime(), tz, "MM:dd HH:mm") + " :";
            body += events[i].getTitle() + " - " + events[i].getDescription() + "   -   Deleted\n";
            events[i].deleteEvent()
        }
    }
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(body);
}
```

Just go through the notes or details mentioned in the site.

http://cybernol.blogspot.in/2016/03/how-to-delete-google-calendar-past.html

Comment: A legitimate approach, still to this day - just used a derivative of this to set up an auto-purge X days back from the calendar. Thank you!